# selenium click using span class or onclick

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to java and selenium webdriver. I am having an issue clicking an image. Below is the page source.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="HomeButton" onclick="javascript:onBtnHomeClick();"/>
</a>
```

I tried below codes but did not work and still getting the Unable to locate element error.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='onBtnHomeClick()']")).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_AppContainer']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span"))).click();


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("HomeButton"))).click();
```

I have to click the homebutton. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Click on Upvote / Accept, for , my answer if my locator works. provided this is your application functionality it will always work even if minor changes will be present. Also this is one of your best strategies  for non break ability.

Comment: Any luck with my Xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `By.className("HomeButton")` didn't work but you have errors in the other two.

In `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='onBtnHomeClick()']")).click();` the tag for `onclick` is `<span>` not `<a>`. It also not `onBtnHomeClick()` but `javascript:onBtnHomeClick();`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@onclick='javascript:onBtnHomeClick();']")).click();
```

If you want to use `onBtnHomeClick()` use contains

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@onclick, 'onBtnHomeClick')]")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("onclick*='onBtnHomeClick'")).click();
```

And in `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_AppContainer']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span"))).click();` the `<span>` parent tag is `<a>`, not `<div>`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_AppContainer']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the correct locator IF your element will be eventually visible.

```
Xpath = "//span[contains(@class,'HomeButton') and contains(@onclick,'onBtnHomeClick')]"
```

Add wait as needed above exanmple, that should work.